# Python Dataset Class + PyTorch Dataloader: Stuck at __getitem__, how to get Index, Label and so on during Testing?

Tags: python, machine-learning, dataset, pytorch, dataloader

I have a, maybe small problem but I am stuck for quite a while now. Hope someone can help me with that. I am currently on a Kddcup99 dataset which I like to train via DeepLearning (CNN Network)

I have a "Dataset" Class which includes the Panda Dataframe. Thus i split up into normal and validate dataset. So far, no problem. 
I load it into a Numpy vector, torch it to Tensor and then direct it to the DataLoader.

The Dataset Class has these two important classes for iterating through:

```
def __len__(self):
        return len(self.val_df)

def __getitem__(self, index):        
        img, target = self.val_df[index][:-1], self.val_df[index][-1]
        return img, target, index
```

Not in the class is the DataLoader string:

```
test_dataloader = DataLoader(datat.val_df, batch_size=10, shuffle=True)
```

In my Trainer Class i have a for loop which should iterate through the Dataloader:

```
with torch.no_grad():
            for data in dataloader:
                inputs, labels, idx = data
                inputs = inputs.to(self.device)
```

But it won't. I can't access the labels, index and such.

My question is now: Why?
**How can I access Labels, Index from the given Dataset via the Dataloader?**

Thank you all for your help! 
Much appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument to [`DataLoader`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader) is the dataset from which you want to load the data, that's usually a [`Dataset`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.Dataset), but it's not restricted to any instance of `Dataset`. As long as it defines the length (`__len__`) and can be indexed (`__getitem__` allows that) it is acceptable.

You are passing `datat.val_df` to the `DataLoader`, which is presumably a NumPy array. A NumPy array has a length and can be indexed, so it can be used in the `DataLoader`. Since you pass that array directly, your dataset's `__getitem__` is never called, but the array itself is indexed, so every item is just `data.val_df[index]`.

Instead of using the underlying data for the `DataLoader`, you have to use the dataset itself (`datat`):

```py
test_dataloader = DataLoader(datat, batch_size=10, shuffle=True)
```

Comment: Firstly: Sorry for the late answer. I hadn't checked here in a while. Your answer solved my problem completely and in a very good way. Thank you!